# return string of values of vector based on level in R

Tags: r, levels

Sorry if this is a basic question, i'm very new to R.

Say I have a vector with certain values with these levels:

```
x=c(3,1,2,1)
levels(x)[c(1,2,3)]=c("Coins","Mix", "Liquid")
```

How can I return a vector of `x` with the values of the level as a string (e.g. "Liquid", "Coins", "Mix", "Coins").

Thanks

Comment: Probably you want `factor(x,labels=c("Coins","Mix", "Liquid"))`..? It's documented in the help file for factors, but the terminology is rather confusing (levels = the integers in the background; labels = the strings in the foreground ... or something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a weird way to format data, but here's an answer:

```
levels(x)[x]
```

Comment: As created above, `x` has no levels.

Comment: This works great thanks. It was the issue with printing the values of the levels rather than creating the levels which i could do.